# How to handle different login credentials for modules in one project?

Tags: php, security, session-variables

I am fairly new to PHP programming and I think I might have some security issues with session variables.

I am currently working on a project which has 3 modules which require separate login credentials.
The 3 modules are for students, teachers and administration.

After the user logs in the respective portals, these credentials are stored as session variables. Let's say we have 2 tabs open in the browser, 1 has the student portal open and the other has the admin portal open. If the student logs in the first portal with **user id 1** shortly after the admin has loged in with **user id 2**, then the userid for both the portal appears to be the same(**userid 1**).  The problem is the session variables for both the portals are getting shared in the browser.

Sometimes session variables are also pulled from previous session in a new tab even after closing it.(*tested it using var_dump[$_SESSION]*)

Can somebody please explain to me how to limit the session variables to each portals or provide me with some hints about other ways of security handling in php?

PS: I have logout buttons which clears up the session variables. The problem seems to persist if the tab is closed or a new portal is opened in the new tab.

thanks in advance.

Comment: In reality, how often will both student and admin login at the same time on the same PC using the same browser?

Comment: It is not very likely that the student and admin will log in on the same PC at the same time but I would still like to know if there is a secure way to handle this issue.

Comment: Probably the securest way is to have separate subdomains for each portal/module, so that the session cookies are domain specific

Comment: In reality, both suggestions from @MarkBaker are correct and should be considered. I provided an answer for a possible solution that disregards those aspects.

Comment: A very funny thing happened to me in work today: I was implementing security for an educational portal with three levels of access (student, teacher, admin). In my case, if someone is already logged in to the VLE, and a new instance is opened in a new tab in the same browser, it will be for the same user already logged in.

Comment: I still do not understand the concepts of domains and sub-domains but I will do some research on it and try to implement it.

Comment: @MarkBaker That is exactly what is happening with my project too. I will change the session variables for each portal and see how it works out. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a browser to a server only one PHP session will be started (apart from private browsing options, but that's off topic) and that is "shared" among all tabs. In contrast to what @fejese's answer suggests, you can solve your situation with using only one PHP session. Your problem probably is that you use the same session variable to indicate that someone is logged in regardless of the access level of that logged in user.

As your 3 separate modules handle authentication, create 3 different session variables that indicate which user is logged in. For e.g. when a student logs in, craete `$_SESSION['auth_student_id']` and assign the logged user (student) ID to it. When a teacher logs in, create `$_SESSION['auth_teacher_id']`, and so forth.

Then, depending on which portal is loaded, ignore the other session variables. So if in tab 1 the student portal is loaded, check for `$_SESSION['auth_student_id']` and ignore the others. If that is set, you know the portal should show protected content because the user (student) has authenticated themselves. If in tab 2 the teacher portal loaded do the same with `$_SESSION['auth_teacher_id']` and ignore the other 2.

Comment: This seems to be a viable option. Having different session variables would avoid the collision. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should consider another approach, using some kind of permission based Access Control rather than different credentials. It would make a much more flexible system.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options:

1. **Change "session_name" on a portal basis**

If you change the session name, the cookies that identify the session will be different from portal to portal. Note that *no* session will be shared this way. If the user logged to a portal, he'll need to log again to the others.

1. **Implement session namespaces**

You could set an array in the main $_SESSION object, one for each submodule, and use each array as if you are using the session directly. With this approach you can share the sessions (easily implementing SSO between the portals), but raises some security concerns. It's valuable to implement an API to access the session if you go this way.